# mysql stop working, using cos, sin etc

Tags: php, mysql, trigonometry

I have a website that was up and running fine until recently. The google maps api to get the lon/lat changed so I updated to the new one. However, now I get constant mysql query errors. I at first assumed my fetch of the lon/lat was incorrect so forced the values but I still get an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*PI()/180) ) ) , 1) AS distance, ' at line 5

The long is 56.562016 and lat is -2.580324 query is below.

```
        $earthRadius = '3963.0'; // In miles

        $sql = "
            SELECT
                ROUND(
                    $earthRadius * ACOS(
                        SIN( $latitude*PI()/180 ) * SIN( latitude*PI()/180 )
                        + COS( $latitude*PI()/180 ) * COS( latitude*PI()/180 )  *  COS( (longitude*PI()/180) - ($longitude*PI()/180) )   )
                , 1)
                AS distance,
                id,
                name,
                description,
                latitude,
                longitude
            FROM
                child
            ORDER BY
                distance ASC
            LIMIT 0, 1";
```

Comment: What are the values of `$longitude` and `$latitude`?

Comment: `var_dump($sql)` will help

Comment: `$latitude` or `latitude`? or both?

Answer (score 0):

The mysql-error indicates that the variable `$longitude` is empty.

Check the values and make sure that they're set. Error handling even works in php. :)